# Is it possible to access this (external) JSON data in my angularJS app?

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

The URL I wish to access is:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=2&appid=570&market_hash_name=Formed%20Alloy%20Set
```

and I'm wondering if it's possible to parse this in AngularJS? I'm unfamiliar with JSONP so I don't quite understand the process. Also the headers returned are application/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam API does not [support jsonp](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)  - it means that you can't access it through javascript XMLHttpRequest. One possible workaround could be to implement a server side proxy and wrap a steam API call with this proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its definitely possible. Inject the [$http resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) into your controller and your call could look something like this:

**Javascript**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(URL).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: this will fail on Same Origin Policy

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question as referring to a generic url get, rather than steam API specific.